# Jetpack Compose Scaffold Overlaps with System Controls (Statusbar and Navigation Controls)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Scaffold Overlaps with system controls like statusbar and navigation buttons
[image]

I am setting these flags in my activity (I think these flags are the reason). any suggestion on how to avoid the overlapping ?

```
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
window.setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED or
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG
            or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
            or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
)
```

I have tried adding Modifiers to the scaffold, but no luck.

```
modifier = Modifier.navigationBarsPadding()
```

How can I solve this issue ?

Code

```
Scaffold(
  scaffoldState = scaffoldWithDrawerState,
  drawerContent = {
     SideDrawerHeader(onViewProfileClicked = {})
     SideDrawerBody(onSidebarMenuItemClicked = {})
  },
  bottomBar = {
    BottomBar(navController = navController)
  }
) { paddingValues ->
     DestinationsNavHost( // navhost(from compose destinations library
       navGraph = NavGraphs.app,
       navController = navController
     )
  }
```

Comment: Are you using https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN some where??

Comment: Also the “or”s might be your issue. Not 100%

Comment: @CayceK no i am not using SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN. I am using only those flags i mentioned above.

Comment: Can you add a snippet of your theme code from the system?

Comment: also what OS is this? I am very curious so I'm trying to replicate and it isn't happening.

Comment: old version of android, Android 7.0 Nougat.

Answer (score 1):

So testing on a Nougat device I see the issue for sure.

`WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG` is the trigger.

Using

```
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
window.setFlags(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED or
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED or
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON,
)
```

Does what you want it to do, but I'm not sure why the `TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG` is causing this issue. What seems to be happening is you seem to be turning your app into a "lockscreen" variant, but that is weird and doesn't sound right. I believe all you need to do is remove the line with `TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG` and you'll be fine. Unless you have a definitive reason to have that there. I can't seem to think of one.

Alternatively.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Adding this style to your style.xml and referencing it in your AndroidManifest as below does the same thing.

```
 <application
        ...
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```